# what should be input into the brackets of $this->paginate()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am using cakephp 1.26.
I am doing some self-learning about Pagination in CakePHP.

I have tested the following code in my localhost, and it works fine.
I have altered a little change to the second line of code, and found that 
nothing change to the result.

1st version:

```
$this->paginate=array('conditions'=>array('Testing.zero'=>'0'), 'limit' => 3);
$w = $this->paginate(); 
$this->set('postVariable', $w);
```

2nd version:

```
$this->paginate=array('conditions'=>array('Testing.zero'=>'0'), 'limit' => 3);
$w = $this->paginate('Testing'); 
$this->set('postVariable', $w);
```

3rd version:

```
$this->paginate=array('conditions'=>array('Testing.zero'=>'0'), 'limit' => 3);
$w = $this->paginate('helloworld'); 
$this->set('postVariable', $w);
```

4th version:

```
$this->paginate=array('conditions'=>array('Testing.zero'=>'0'), 'limit' => 3);
$w = $this->paginate($this->helloworld); 
$this->set('postVariable', $w);
```

I have no idea what I should input into the brackets of $this->paginate()

Comment: @Anax
Let's think of the case that you have a daytime job to do and you are doing some self-learning until mid-night; or that would be another thing if you dont have a job.

Comment: That's the case of most of us here. Still, clicking on a check mark won't take you more than 2 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation says it all: http://api.cakephp.org/class/controller#method-Controllerpaginate

First parameter is the model name, second parameter is a scope, that is, an additional conditions array. Third parameter is currently useless.

Comment: Also, here's a link to the Cookbook which describes this feature: http://book.cakephp.org/view/165/Controller-Setup

Answer (score 1):

The `paginate` function can be found in `/cake/libs/controller/controller.php`,line 934.It's a bit long but not that complex.And I think you can read it and find the reason yourself.Personally I prefer current model name as the parameter.In your code ,that would be

```
$w = $this->paginate("Testing");
```